# How binding of Silverlight UI to .NET Classes works

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am looking at binding a certain silverlight UI to a C# class. In the example code below there are two textboxes in the XAML page. Any changes made to one textbox is reflected in the other the minute it loses focus and vice-versa. While the example I have works as I want it to, I have no clue as to what is goin on under the hood and how it works that way.

Here is the C# code

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FirstName 
    { 
        get
        {return firstname;} 

        set
        {   firstname = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("FirstName");
        } 

    }
    private string firstname;

    void FirePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Grid in the mainpage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="MyLayoutRoot" Background="White" ShowGridLines="True"> 
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Codebehind for Mainpage.xaml

```
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);
    }

    void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person p = new Person()
        {
            FirstName ="Dee"
        };
        MyLayoutRoot.DataContext = p;
    }
}
```

My understanding so far which is a bit hazy now is this:

The textbox in the xaml(mainpage.xaml) knows what property to bind to based on its "Binding" tag, from the class (Person) it was setup with, in the xaml codebehind file(mainpage.xaml.cs) by using the datacontext property there.

INotifyPropertyChanged is an interface in the person class, that provides some hook that allows the Xaml UI to know when the Firstname property got changed in the UI.
The minute the Firstname property is set, the FirePropertyChanged method gets called which triggers this event **PropertyChangedEventHandler** as is implemented in this line

`PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));`

Can anyone elaborate on what goes on behind the scenes here at this moment, when one of the textboxes changes and loses focus; and how does the Binding property on the Silverlight client side UI, maintain contact with the C# class which, correct me if I am wrong is still on the server that the silverlight UI was downloaded from.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

If the Person class is in the same Silverlight UI project, then it is actually on the client (not the server). Maybe this makes it easier to understand?

Comment: It doesnt have to be. I my example it was. but in real life scenarios I would assume this class to be from the data layer which is not ported across along with the silverlight UI

Comment: Ok, well I dont think the binding would work in that case. I might be wrong

Comment: In that case you'd have to transport your data to the client somehow, and then bind to the client objects. Bindings are not THAT magical, they don't span the internet ;)

Comment: if Im not mistaken the only thing that gets transportedto the client is the xap file.. does the c# class get embedded in it?

Comment: The Silverlight client project gets compiled into the XAP file. If your Person class is in this project, then yes it will be compiled into the XAP file and transported to the client.
Like Bubblewrap said, this kind of binding wont automatically work between the client and server (over the internet)

Comment: so then one needs to maintain a class in the xap file and then using wcf pull data to/from the database and into that class..correct?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it.